# How to have display buckets like android in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am planning to build a react native app.The app gets targetted to 3 main things.

1ft => Mobiles(IOS,ANDROID),

2ft => Tablets,

10ft => Android TV.

How can we create files so that if I want to build for 1ft(Mobiles),the app should take only 1ft files like

eg; 1ft_android.js,1ft_ios.js

eg; 2ft_android.js ,2ft_ios.js

and in the same how can I build separately without using Platform.Select Or is there any chance to use flavours and is there any way to make this happen?

> Edit 1: I have the folder structure as follows:

[image]

> I want to find a way to let react know that if display metric matches
>   1ft, take landing.1ft.android.js. I don't want to compare display
>   metrics everytime. I'm looking for some configuration so react will
>   pick the respective file like it picks platform specific files.

Answer (score 1):

***For Platform specific UI you can Switch using Platform module.***

```
import {Platform, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 200 : 100,
});
```

> But if you want to create responsive UI which will adjust its shape
>   and size with respect to screen you can use the following methods:

Flex: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width#flex-dimensions

Screen ratio:

```
var deviceWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width;
...
myImage { width: deviceWidth, height: deviceWidth * 0.5 }
```

> And for font-size you can use this function:

```
export const getAdjustedFontSize = (size) => {
    return parseInt(size) * metrics.screenWidth * (1.8 - 0.002 * metrics.screenWidth) / 400;
};
```

Edit:

You can refer to this link also: https://medium.com/react-native-training/build-responsive-react-native-views-for-any-device-and-support-orientation-change-1c8beba5bc23

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not answer my question, I didn't ask for platform specific layout, My question is about segregating Components with respect to display sizes.

Comment: @anudeepn I have already added flex and screen ratio with this two methods you can easily create responsive design for any layout

Comment: I hope @anudeep is asking for display specific buckets for segregating layouts like hdpi, xhdpi in react native.

Comment: @ManojPrabhakar There is no need to add layouts like hdpi, xhdpi in react native and for images you can add @ for 3x images : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20655